# Recoloring math in an equation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, color

I have a presentation with the color for math changed to blue:

```
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black!15!blue}
```

Everything looks nice, until I want to recolor part of an equation:

```
\begin{align*}
   x\ y\ z &: A  \color{red}\longleftarrow \text{Assumptions}\\
   \hline
   x &\in \color{red}\underbrace{[x,y,z]}_{\text{Goal}}
\end{align*}
```

Then it just goes bananas: half of the left arrow is printed in blue, and the brace is totally printed in blue.

Any help will be appreciated.

The entire code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black!15!blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{align*}
      x\ y\ z &: A  \color{red}\longleftarrow \text{Assumptions}\\
      \hline
      x &\in \color{red}\underbrace{[x,y,z]}_{\text{Goal}}
   \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting question. Workaround before the proper solution is found: `\mathrel{\text{\color{red}$\longleftarrow$}}` and `\text{\color{red}$\underbrace{[x,y,z]}_{\text{Goal}}$}`

Comment: Thanks yo', David, and Joseph. I like David's version better, but thanks Joseph for the nice explanation!

Answer (score 14):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black!15!blue}

\newcommand\beamermathcolor[1]{\color{#1}\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{align*}
      x\ y\ z &: A  \beamermathcolor{red}\longleftarrow \text{Assumptions}\\
      \hline
      x &\in \beamermathcolor{red}\underbrace{[x,y,z]}_{\text{Goal}}
   \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234217), you could reset `\everymath` here

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black!15!blue}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{frame}
   \begin{align*}
     \global\everymath{}
      x\ y\ z &: A \color{red}\longleftarrow \text{Assumptions}\\
      \hline
      x &\in \color{red}\underbrace{[x,y,z]}_{\text{Goal}}
   \end{align*}
  \global\everymath{\beamer@setmathcolor}
\end{frame}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The oddness happens becuase the math color is applied *via* `\everymath`, and if you trace through the code some bits of the 'text' use math mode. For example `\longleftarrow` is made up of various parts, some in math mode and some not.